Debug AWS Amplify Lambda Function Locally in Python
I am trying to debug line by line my lambda funtion developed in Python. As I am working with Amplify, I execute the command amplify mock function but it only executes the function without developing.
I added the python debugging in VSC Configuration.
I need to debug line by line the Lambda Function locally

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

sam local start-api
That will start a local API Gateway and your Lambda function.
Use a tool like Postman or cURL to send requests to your local Lambda function. The endpoint URL will be displayed in the console when you start the local API.
To debug your Lambda function, you can use the built-in Python debugger (pdb) or any other Python debugging tool. Add breakpoints in your code using breakpoint() or import pdb; pdb.set_trace().
When you send a request to your local Lambda function, the debugger will pause the execution at the breakpoints, and you can step through the code, inspect variables, and analyze the behavior of your function.
